# Move the files older than three hours to archive folder without overwriting existing files

Tags: perl

The below script will move the files having modification time older than three hours from `/tmp/test1` folder to `/data/ARCHIVE` folder.

The issue is that if the `ARCHIVE` folder already has a file with same name as in the `test1` folder it will overwrite them, which is unwanted.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my $dstdir = '/data/ARCHIVE/';

@ARGV = ("/tmp/test1") unless @ARGV;

print STDERR "Begin @ ", scalar localtime, "\n";

find(
    sub {
        if ( -f $_ && -M _ >= 3 / 24 ) {
            print STDERR "Moving '$_'\n";
            move( $File::Find::name, $dstdir ) or die "$!\n";
        }
    },
    @ARGV
);

print STDERR "Ended @ ", scalar localtime, "\n";

1;
```

Comment: What would be your desired behavior if there are files that would be overwritten? There are many potential alternatives, including not overwriting, halting with an error, writing the files to a different folder, re-naming the files so there is no overwrite, etc. etc.

Comment: Either the data should be append with same file name or the file name will get renamed with filename _1,filename_2 every time the file is being moved to ARCHIVE folder having same name as in test1 folder.

Comment: You don't appear to have attempted to code for this situation at all, which makes me think that you've simply copied this code from somewhere and want us to "fix it up" for you. That isn't going to happen. Make your best attempt and ask for help if you find it impossible to get it working. Hint: the new file will be `"$dstdir/$_"` and it makes sense to check whether it exists before you do the `move`.

Comment: OK -- if you could try to achieve the outcome you are looking and find you cannot do it, you could then ask a specific question about the problem you encounter. Hint: How would you check that a given file name already exists and, if you find that the file already exists, how could you modify the filename by appending characters to give the naming scheme that you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Add the epoch to the file name. But don't run your code more than once a second.

```
my $now = strftime( '%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime );
find(
    sub {
        if ( -f $_ && -M _ >= 3 / 24 ) {
            print STDERR "Moving '$_'\n";
            my $dst = "$dstdir/$_.$now";
            move( $File::Find::name, $dst ) or die "$!\n";
        }
    },
    @ARGV
);
```

Comment: This above solution worked for me. I am a newbie in perl trying to understand things. Thanks all for your support.